# i want to find the second last element in the list

Tags: python-3.x

```
n=int(input())
arr=[]
i=1
while i<=n:
    arr.append(int(input()))
    i=i+1
s=len(arr)
sorted(arr)
print(arr[-2])

#error is:
>Traceback (most recent call last):
 > File "Solution.py", line 5, in <module>
 >   arr.append(int(input()))
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'

Comment: What is your input? your code is to enter input in the first line and fifth line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```py
arr=list(map(int, input().split()))
s=len(arr)
sorted(arr)
print(arr[-2])
```

You  were entering a list of elements which were space separated. You don't need `n` at all. Just split the input and convert each  entry to integer and store  it in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You're giving input all at once in line number 5 - '2 3 6 6 5'.
Your code expects a single value at a time. Hence for `n=5` you need to enter 5 values, one at a time, till your while loop is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing to go off of... but perhaps this will help?!?

```py
n = int(input('give me a number: '))
arr = []
i = 1
while i < n:
  print(n)
  arr.append(int(input('This does not matter but, I will remember your answer: ')))
  i = i + 1
s=len(arr)
sorted(arr)
print('I am going to tell you your second to last "does not matter" answer')
print(arr[-2])
```

Output:

```
give me a number: 5
5
This does not matter but, I will remember your answer: 1
5
This does not matter but, I will remember your answer: 2
5
This does not matter but, I will remember your answer: 3
5
This does not matter but, I will remember your answer: 4
I am going to tell you your second to last "does not matter" answer
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with arrayName[-2] or arrayName[len(arrayName) - 2]